# Editable Select Option Tag

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

I want to make my table column row *editable* by select option tag. Here is my code:

```
<td>
    <select name="mpn[]" id="mpn" style="width: 55px; float: left;" onchange="this.nextElementSibling.value=this.value">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="Post" <?php $a=set_select('mpn[0]','Post',  ( !empty($a) && $a == "Post" ? TRUE : FALSE )); echo $a; ?>>Post</option>
          <option value="Neg" <?php $a=set_select('mpn[0]','Neg',  ( !empty($a) && $a == "Neg" ? TRUE : FALSE )); echo $a; ?>>Neg</option>
          <option value="Values" <?php $a=set_select('mpn[0]','Values',  ( !empty($a) && $a == "Values" ? TRUE : FALSE )); echo $a; ?>>Values</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="mpn[]" id="mpn" value="<?php $a=set_value('mpn[0]'); echo $a; ?>" style="width: 35px; margin-left: -54px; margin-top: 1px; border: none; float: left;"/>
</td>
```

Above code already work for each options `Post, Neg, Values` and inserted into my database table field, but if i insert editable value for example i select option `Values` and edit to value *100*, option `Values` still inserted into my database table field. Why the new value (editable values) is not inserted into my table ?

Any help would be appreciated greatly, thanks.

Comment: Where is your PHP code?

Comment: Are you sure that you edit option values? or option display text?